# python determine json attributes

Tags: python

I want to determine each attribut in a JSON format where i have no idea about the content of the JSON file.

For example i have these different files contenent:

```
[
{
    "name": "abc",
    "hobby": "swimming"
},
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "hobby": "programming"
}
]
```

and the second example:

```
[
{
    "street": "PL EDOUARD BOUILLIERE",
    "nb_places_totales": 249
},
{
    "street": "CHE DU VERDON",
    "nb_places_totales": 212
}
]
```

How can i parse and determine the attribut name using python?

Comment: It looks like your JSON consists of a `list` of `dict` values. You can iterate over the `list` first and then run `for key, value in dict.item()` to iterate over the `dict` values. The `key` will contain the JSON keys you are looking for.

Comment: the above should be `.items()` not `.item()`... that is: 

`for key, value in dict.items():`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the json package to parse the file.  Then you can look at the keys of the first item in the data structure.

```
import json

with open(filename) as fid:
    data = json.load(fid)

print(data[0].keys())
```

Comment: And if i get enclosed attributs for example:
[
{
"geo_shape": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     1.437119162465912,
     43.63540081010507
    ]
   },
"nom": "LA VACHE"
}
]

Comment: In this case `data[0]['geo_shape'].keys()`.  You just need to index into the list/dict structure until you get to the appropriate level.  If loop over entries to get all of of the keys at a certain level, you can use a `set` object to get the unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = """[
{
    "name": "abc",
    "hobby": "swimming"
},
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "hobby": "programming"
}
]"""

import json
d = json.loads(data) # here I am loading from the string, but you can load from a json file by using json.load() instead of json.loads()

 # iterate through the list of dicts and print the keys for each dict
for _ in d:
    print _.keys()
```

this will result in:

```
[u'hobby', u'name']
[u'hobby', u'name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for dictionary keys, in python3:

```
import json

a = json.loads("""
[{"name": "abc", "hobby": "swimming" },
{"name": "xyz", "hobby": "programming"}]
""")

b = json.loads("""
[{"street": "PL EDOUARD BOUILLIERE", "nb_places_totales": 249},
{"street": "CHE DU VERDON", "nb_places_totales": 212 }]
""")

print(*(i.keys() for i in a))
print(*(i.keys() for i in b))
```

but every solution will be somehow content dependent anyway.

Answer (score -2):

This is how you get the attribute name. If you want values, print value instead of key.

```
import json
import sys

obj1 = [
{
    "name": "abc",
    "hobby": "swimming"
},
{
    "man": "xyz",
    "hobby": "programming"
}
]

obj2 = [
{
    "street": "PL EDOUARD BOUILLIERE",
    "nb_places_totales": 249
},
{
    "street": "CHE DU VERDON",
    "nb_places_totales": 212
}
]

print "Obj1 Attributes"
for i in range(0, len(obj1)):
    for key, value in obj1[i].items():
        print key


print "Obj2 Attributes"
for j in range(0, len(obj2)):
    for key, value in obj2[i].items():
        print key
```

Comment: Then remove the first loop..??